# read from behind in line in the file

Tags: python

I'm basically solving one problem here

```
with open("input.txt", "r",encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

I want this code to read one part from the beginning and the other from the end and combine it into one

Here is an example text file I have:

```
hello i would like to help
I appreciate it really much
maybe I'll pay you back someday
thank you very much for your help
```

output is new file

```
    print(line,":",line1, file=open(""+str("treti")+".txt", "a",encoding='utf-8'),sep='')


1 hello i would like to help:thank you very much for your help
2 I appreciate it really much:maybe I'll pay you back someday
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways you can do this.
Here are two examples.

In the first one you relate on the index, in the 2nd you just zip the list once from the start and once from the end and add each iteration the lines together.

```
1) 
for i in range(len(lines)//2):
    s = lines[i].strip()
    e = lines[-1-i].strip()
    print(s, ':', e)

2) 

for i, (line_s, line_e) in enumerate(zip(lines, lines[::-1])):
    if i == len(lines)//2:
        break
    print(f"{line_s.strip()} : {line_e.strip()}")
```

Ouputs in both:

```
hello i would like to help : thank you very much for your help
I appreciate it really much : maybe I'll pay you back someday
```

Comment: yes working thanx  if you can give him someone a positive review please give it to him